# Keeping an MVC 6 Project Up to Date

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

A few weeks ago, I started working with projects based on the MVC 6 / ASP.NET 5 templates in Visual Studio 2015.

I noticed that these templates referenced the beta5 version of the assemblies.

Last week, I found a way to update the templates so that they would include the beta7 version of the assemblies using the download located [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623894).

While working on a library project this morning, I discovered that I needed to reference the latest version of the nightly builds (the beta8 version).  I manually updated all of the references in a web application project to update from beta7 to beta8.  When I did this, the application stopped working (I simply receive a 404 error when using routes that previously worked).

My question is this:  is there a *trick* to keeping a web application project up to date with the nightly build versions?

Comment: No, it's the nightly builds of a highly experimental technology - no one is going to invest a month to build tooling that would be irrelevant in a few months. Your best bets with MVC6 is to hang out in the jabbr where a bunch of people from the asp.net team lurk and ask them stuff when you get stuck because your build breaks. I'm sure they would also appreciate the feedback.

Comment: if you decide to live with nightly builds, don't forget to "watch" the [announcements](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements) repo for breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

For nuget packages, you may use "*" to refer to the latest version. you may take a look at the [project.json](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/src/MusicStore/project.json#L14-L37) file in MusicStore repo for example. I copied relevant section here:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.InMemory": "7.0.0-*",
        "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Antiforgery": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-*",
    }
}
```